# Should i enable 3rd party cookie for Android WebView?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I'm working with WebView on Android and have a requirement to enable 3rd party cookie for all web domain to write cookie. I have some concerns:

1. If i enable 3rd party cookie, what is the security issue for the app information and for user?
2. From Android K and below, 3rd cookie is enabled by default; Android L and above, 3rd party cookie is disable by default; i wonder why they changes this behaviors?
3. I've searched on internet for recommendation to enable or disable cookie, but there aren't much there. I wonder if there are some recommendations for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Enable third party cookie in webview.

```
webView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
webView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
```

Set cookie to webview.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
 } else {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
 }


for (String cookie: cookies) { //parse your cookies and set one by one. edit your method here
                cookieManager.setCookie(getString(R.string.urlInsta), cookie);
            }
```

If you have query please let me know.

Comment: Hi Tushar, thank for your feedback, but what i concern is what is security issue i can face when i enable 3rd party cookie.

Comment: @TrieuTran which security issue are you asking? please explain more.